# Is there a "loop" scope in ColdFusion?

Tags: loops, coldfusion, scope

I'm building an SQL query with a `cfloop` and want to control my commas.

Given a loop like so:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(local.fields)#" index="local.i">
    <cfif local.fields[local.i][1]>
        -- NEXT LINE IS OF INTEREST
        <cfif IsNull(local.passedFirst)> <cfset local.passedFirst = True > <cfelse> , </cfif>
        #local.fields[local.i][2]# as '#local.fields[local.i][3]#'
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

It works great once, but **I want to drop `passedFirst` when I exit the loop.**

Currently, the next time I do a loop using local.passedFirst, it remembers that I set it to `True`.

So, **is there a "loop" scope in ColdFusion?**

*EDIT: I found a solution unrelated to the question title*

While there is no "loop" scope to use a flag like this in a one-liner, I found an unrelated way around my problem in order to build my `SELECT`:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(local.fields)#" index="local.i">
    <cfif local.fields[local.i][1]>
        #local.fields[local.i][2]# as '#local.fields[local.i][3]#' ,
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Since this query always has a row *after* the loop above, I can *append* the comma instead of *prepending* the comma.

Comment: There is no loop scope.  From the code you posted, you have the variables local.fields, and local.i to work with.  As far as local.passedFirst is concerned, the StructDelete command might work.

Comment: I was kind of assuming he was inside a function - hence the use of local. no?

Comment: Correct, I am inside a function.

Comment: Hey @Mickelain with questions like this, it's pretty easy to try it for yourself and find out, innit? You clearly understand the principles you're asking about, so it's like four lines of code to test...?

Comment: @AdamCameron Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "it" in your first sentence? I did not ask my question due to lack of testing or research; I tested scopes that might have worked, and researched for scopes I may not have known about. I simply didn't know if that kind of scope existed in CF (as it exists implicitly in other languages).

Comment: @Mickelain: "it" == "your question". Lemme gist something to demonstrate all you'd need to have done to answer your own question: https://gist.github.com/daccfml/b752e51f959b30af22c2

Comment: @AdamCameron Yep, I tested exactly that. `variables`, `local`, and `unscoped` each did not work as a `loop` scope. I kept searching, found nothing, posted here, and got my answer from Mark. Next time I'll make it obvious that I did my own tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no loop scope as you describe. You will need to drop passedFirst before you enter your next loop:

```
<cfset structDelete(local,"passedfirst")/>
```

Or you can simply clear local as in:

```
<cfset structClear(local)/>
```

local is a scope in a function of course - is that where you are using it? Do you have a function with more than one loop?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple loops in this function. Thank you for telling me how to clear the variable from local; that seems to be the most relevant solution to what I was asking. You also answered my question in the title, so I accepted your answer.